# iOS - are there alternatives to Apple push notifications if I have my own server?

Tags: sockets, ios7, notifications, alert

I have an app server and several iOS apps that communicate with this app server over the internet. I'm trying to understand **if there are any other frameworks, other than Apple Push notifications that allow me to send a message to a specific user of my app while the app is open?**

A typical scenario: I type a message at a console on the app server and the message box pops up on a specific device.

One possible approach that I thought of is to periodically poll the server for messages for this particular device. Another approach would be to keep a socket open and stream messages over that socket from the server.

Comment: Both of those approaches will really impact a users battery life. Is there a reason you don't want to use Apple Push Notifications? FYI iOS 8 will apparently display battery usage by app.

Comment: The app will run on iPads that will be provided to the user for a short time, they will be recharged between users.